# Finitely additive function on an infinite set, s.t., $m(A)=0$ for any finite set and $m(X)=1$ (constructive approach)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof, filters

Other exercise which I found in Dudley's Analysis book:

> Show that there is a measure on a infinite set $X$, defined on $2^X$ s.t. is finitely additive, $m(A)=0$ for any finite set and $m(X)=1$.

The solution is very simple using the Frechet filter $\mathcal{F}:=\{A: X\setminus A \text{ finite}\}$ and defining the measure on the ultrafilter $\mathfrak{U}$ containing $\mathcal{F}$, as follows

$$m(A)=\begin{cases} 1& A\in \mathfrak{U}\\
0&A\notin \mathfrak{U} \end{cases}$$

For the following

> **Lemma**: Let $\mathfrak{U}$ be an ultrafilter of subsets of $X$ and let $m$ defined as above. Then $m$ is finitely additive on $2^X$.

PF: It's clear that $\varnothing\notin \mathfrak{U}$, so $m(\varnothing)=0$. Let $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^N\subset 2^{X}$ and disjoint, and let $A$ be their union. We consider two cases: If all are not in $ \mathfrak{U}$, i.e, $X\setminus A_n\in \mathfrak{U}$ for $n\le N$. Thus $X\setminus A=\bigcap_{n\le N}X\setminus A_n\in \mathfrak{U}$, so $A\notin \mathfrak{U}$. Hence $m(A)=\sum_{n\le N}m(A_n)=0$

Now suppose that at least one is in $\mathfrak{U}$. Let $A_1\in \mathfrak{U}$, so all the other elements are not in $\mathfrak{U}$ since otherwise $\varnothing=A\cap A_i\in \mathfrak{U}$ for $i\not=1$. Since $A_1\subset A$ and $A_1\in \mathfrak{U}$,  $A\in\mathfrak{U}$. Thus $m(A)=\sum_{n\le N}m(A_n)=1$. $\Box$

Does someone know if there is hope of a constructive approach? I believe the answer is negative...

Comment: Different exercises, different questions. Would be better.

Comment: What would be better @leo? Put them in different parts.

Comment: Take one exercise out of this question and put it in another question.

Comment: But both are not incredible long, I think @MarkFantini

Comment: It's not about being long, it's about searchability. Two separate exercises in two separate questions is much easier to find than two exercises in one single question.

Comment: The Frechet Filter is not an ultrafilter. It is just a filter. If $\mathcal{U}$ is an ultrafilter over $\mathcal{P}(X)$, then for every $Y \in \mathcal{P}(X)$, $Y \in \mathcal{U}$ **or** $Y \not \in \mathcal{U}$ (where **or** is exclusive). The Frechet Filter does not contain any countable or co-countable sets and thus is **not** an ultrafilter. 

However, your measures is defined correctly and indeed works for any **filter** and therefore works for any ultrafilter.

Answer (score 2):

It is known that existence of a finitely additive measure defined on the whole powerset $2^{\mathbb N}$ which vanishes on finite sets cannot be proved in ZF. So we cannot hope in a *constructive* proof of existence of such measures.

Some posts where you can find further references:

- [ZF and the Existence of Finitely additive measure on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322753/zf-and-the-existence-of-finitely-additive-measure-on-mathcalp-mathbbr/1322817#1322817)
- [How to construct a continuous finite additive measure on the natural numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95954/how-to-construct-a-continuous-finite-additive-measure-on-the-natural-numbers) at MathOverflow
- [Ref. request: Additive probability measure on $\mathcal P({\bf N})$ supplies subset of $\mathbf R$ without Baire property](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209067/ref-request-additive-probability-measure-on-mathcal-p-bf-n-supplies-sub) at MathOverflow

Some references where similar questions are studied:

- Howard, Rubin: *Consequences of the Axiom of Choice*, AMS, 1998. (See [AMS website](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/surv-59) or [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=ffXxBwAAQBAJ).) This book is accompanied by [a website](http://consequences.emich.edu/conseq.htm) where you can search for implications between various consequences of AC and search for models in which a particular consequence of AC holds (or does not hold). Existence of a nonprincipal measure on $2^{\mathbb N}$ is Form 222 in this book. Existence of non-principal measure is Form 221.
- E. Schechter: *Handbook of Analysis and Its Foundations*; It is shown in [29.37](https://books.google.sk/books?id=eqUv3Bcd56EC&pg=PA810) that existence of such measures is equivalent (in ZF) to $\ell_1\subsetneq\ell_\infty^*$ and in [28.38](https://books.google.sk/books?id=eqUv3Bcd56EC&pg=PA811) that it implies existence of a set without Baire property.
- David Pincus and Robert M. Solovay: *[Definability of measures and ultrafilters](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2272118)*. J. Symbolic Logic **42** (1977), no. 2, 179–190.
- Eric K. van Douwen. *[Finitely additive measures on $\mathbb N$](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0166-8641(92)90032-U)*. Topology Appl., **47 (3)**, (1992), 223–268.

Comment: I made this answer CW; if you are aware of further posts and references which might be useful here, feel free to add them.