# Finitely additive shift invariant probability measure on Z

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis

Does anybody know a specific function $\mu$ going from the power set of the integers to $[0,1]$ so that

1). $\mu(\mathbb{Z}) = 1$

2). $\mu(A\cup B) = \mu(A)+\mu(B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

3). $\mu(A+1) = \mu(A)$ where $A+1 := \{a+1 | a \in A\}$?

I've seen how to show one exists but I was wondering if someone could tell me a specific $\mu$ that works, or why it is impossible to construct explicitly such a $\mu$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the fact the you mention that you know about how to prove that such a measure exists, I will give some links, where measures of the following form (or very similar) are mentioned:
$$\mu(A)=\operatorname{\mathcal U-lim} \frac{A\cap[-n,n]}{2n+1}.$$
(Here $\mathcal U$ is any free ultrafilter. Some of these posts deal with measures on $\mathbb N$ rather than $\mathbb Z$, but it is not difficult to modify them.)

It might be also worth mentioning that existence of a shift-invariant finitely additive probability measure is equivalent to existence of [shift-invariant mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group).

In some the linked posts you can find some further references. In particular, van Douwen's paper and the book by Howard and Rubin are certainly worth having a look in connection with this.

- [Finitely Additive not Countably Additive on $\Bbb N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485443/finitely-additive-not-countably-additive-on-bbb-n)
- [Applications of ultrafilters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35450/applications-of-ultrafilters/35461#35461)

---

You cannot expect a very explicit example - since this is not provable in ZF. This is true already if you require the first two conditions. You can find some references here:

- [Finitely additive function on an infinite set, s.t., $m(A)=0$ for any finite set and $m(X)=1$ (constructive approach)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972527/finitely-additive-function-on-an-infinite-set-s-t-ma-0-for-any-finite-set)
- MathOverflow: [How to construct a continuous finite additive measure on the natural numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/q/95954)
- MathOverflow: [Ref. request: Additive probability measure on $\mathcal P({\bf N})$ supplies subset of $\mathbf R$ without Baire property](https://mathoverflow.net/q/209067)